# Optimize this SQL!

Tags: mysql, sql

User access source_slug (say, the_source_slug). System tries to get other distinct source_slugs that other users (who have used the_source_slug) have accessed earlier, sorted by most frequently used to least frequently used. Basically, system is trying to find users with similar interest and show other pages they have accessed earlier.

Need help with optimizing this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(SOURCE_SLUG), COUNT(SOURCE_SLUG) CATCOUNT 
  FROM topsources 
 WHERE SOURCE_SLUG <> ? 
   AND USER_ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT(USER_ID) 
                     FROM topsources WHERE SOURCE_SLUG = ?) 
GROUP BY SOURCE_SLUG ORDER BY CATCOUNT DESC
```

Table Structure:

```
`topsources` (
  `USER_ID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `DATE_AND_HOUR` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `UPDATED_TIME` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `ITEM_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `SOURCE_SLUG` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `FEED_PAGE_URL` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `CATEGORY_SLUG` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `REFERRER` varchar(2048) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`USER_ID`,`DATE_AND_HOUR`(30),`ITEM_ID`),
  KEY `USER_ID` (`USER_ID`),
  KEY `FEED_PAGE_URL` (`FEED_PAGE_URL`),
  KEY `SOURCE_SLUG` (`SOURCE_SLUG`),
  KEY `CATEGORY_SLUG` (`CATEGORY_SLUG`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: You will probably have more luck when answering questions with a question mark instead of making it sound like you are putting us to work...

Comment: I am not putting anyone to work...as a developer, I like challenges...I felt it would challenge other problem solvers too. I also have "need help" in the question.

Comment: how slow is the query currently ? how many rows of data ? can you post the results of: show indexes from <all tables in query> so we can see cardinalities ? can you post a few rows of sample data for the same slug ?

Comment: query takes 3-4 seconds currently. Total rows of data can be max 1000 but is LIMITed to 5. Total rows on the table is 220K

Answer (score 1):

- Use inner join instead of a subselect
- add an index on SOURCE_SLUG

Comment: SOURCE_SLUG is already indexed. Need help with the first though. Thanks for responding in the right spirit

Comment: @Daniel, I am Java/PHP developer...not a sql expert. Not very good at inner joins, distinct and ordering

Comment: Just give it a try. Being able to join isn't going to make you an SQL expert ;-)

Comment: OK...you pushed me hard here. Here's what I have come up with. Can you check if you can further optimize it? `SELECT DISTINCT(ts.SOURCE_SLUG), COUNT(ts.SOURCE_SLUG) CATCOUNT FROM topsources ts
 INNER JOIN topsources tsi
 ON ts.USER_ID = tsi.USER_ID
 AND tsi.SOURCE_SLUG = ?
 WHERE ts.SOURCE_SLUG <> ? AND ts.CATEGORY_SLUG = ? 
 GROUP BY ts.SOURCE_SLUG ORDER BY ts.CATCOUNT DESC LIMIT 5`

Comment: Even with the above query, I am getting different results...the trouble is inner DISTINCT

Comment: What are the different results?

Comment: Different results due to inner DISTINCT in the subselect query. I don't know how to include that inner DISTINCT as part of INNER JOIN query

Comment: "Different result" doesn't help me. How do the results differ? Are you getting "more" with the INNER JOIN?

Comment: catcounts are different. catcounts for INNER JOIN query are very high and so results differ